# SCIP what is the function for sign?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, scip

I am new to SCIP and have read through some of the example problems and documentation, but am still unsure how to formulate the following problem for the SCIP solver:

`argmax(w) sum(sign(Aw) == sign(b))`

where `A` is a nxm matrix, `w` is a mx1 vector, and `b` is a nx1 vector. The data type is floats/real numbers, and it is a constraint-free problem.

Values for `A` and `b` are also contained row-wise in a .txt file. How can I import that?

**Overall** - I am new to SCIP and have no idea how to start creating variables (especially the objective function value parameter), importing data, formulate the objective function... It's a bit of a stretch for me to ask this question, but your help is appreciated!

Comment: Make sure to get the basics of those optimization problems first before implementing. This one line has tons of potential to be *very annoying*(!): equality-comparison and the undifferentiable sign-function. The usual approach is to transform the constraint-free sign/abs problem to a constrained sign/abs-free problem. But i would not do that blindly (without having a clear idea of how my approach is expected to work for my problem). Additionally: asking on how to import data while also asking about modelling is often a sign for bad preparation / very early approaches. Invest some time.

Comment: As @sascha already pointed out: You seem to be quite early in the modelling/development process. I recommend to start with PySCIPOpt (https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt), because the first steps are way easier in Python than in C/C++ - especially when you're also parsing unformatted .txt files.

Comment: Also don't fix yourself on using a sign() function. sign(b) seems to be fixed already and for each entry of Aw, use a binary variable to indicate whether its sign is positive or negative. Then the sum() just becomes a simple sum over binary variables (or their negation, depending on sign(w)).

Comment: I have never seen an objective like this. Looks somewhat familiar to a classification problem. What is the background for this?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

[image]

where `beta(i) = sign(b(i))`. The implication can be implemented using indicator constraints. This way we don't need big-M's.

Most likely the `>= 0` constraint should be `>= 0.0001` (otherwise we can set all `w(j)=0`).